# Woocommerce Plus/Minus buttons on cart

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a code that works just fine for the first time, but once the cart has been updated, the buttons stop working. Here is my HTML

```
<td class="product-quantity" data-title="Quantity">
     <span class="prqu_minus"> </span>
     <div class="quantity">
     <input type="number" step="1" min="0" max="" name="cart[XXXXX][qty]" value="7" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"></div>
     <span class="prqu_plus"> </span>
</td>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.prqu_minus').click(function () {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
    count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
    $input.val(count);
    $input.change();
   $( 'div.woocommerce > form input[name="update_cart"]' ).prop( 'disabled', false );
   return false;
   });
 $('.prqu_plus').click(function () {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
    $input.change();
    $( 'div.woocommerce > form input[name="update_cart"]' ).prop( 'disabled', false );
    return false;
    });                                                                   
 });
```

If you could share a tip on how to make it keep working after hitting "Update Cart" that'd be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: yeah the issue was the event delegation that at first was on document ready and since the html changes after document ready the event doesn't work on the new items. You can answer your own question with the above code so it will be easy for others to read the solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with this:

```
 jQuery(function($) {

$( document ).on( 'click', '[name=prqu_minus]', function() {
     var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
     var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
     count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
     $input.val(count);
     $input.change();
     $( 'div.woocommerce > form input[name="update_cart"]' ).prop( 'disabled', false );
     return false;
});


$( document ).on( 'click', '[name=prqu_plus]', function() {
     var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
     $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
     $input.change();
     $( 'div.woocommerce > form input[name="update_cart"]' ).prop( 'disabled', false );
     return false;
});

});
```